# Downloading xml file from URL

Tags: c#, xml, webclient

I am trying to store data from a xml file located in this link : [Link to xml file](http://farm04.gox.vn/edu/IOE_Exam/IOE/l5/v1/g1/exam1.xml?v=)

The xml file basically contains questions as well as options relating to English grammar. The main reason for saving these file is that I can parse these information later

From the browser (Chrome or IE), the xml file is loaded normally yet saving it programmatically did not work. The issue is that the data retrieved from that URL appeared to be something else.

This is my code for getting data from the URL

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            // the data retrieved is something meaning : "Link does not exist"
            string data = client.DownloadString("http://farm04.gox.vn/edu/IOE_Exam/IOE/l5/v1/g1/exam1.xml?v=");
        }
```

The above approach gives nothing but a string which indicates there isnt such a link (though I still think the server itself sends it rather than a 404 error).

My second attempt is using WebRequest and WebResponse but no luck. I have read that WebClient is a wrapper class for the latter method so both give the same result

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I suppose the server has a mechanism to prevent client from downloading it. However Chrome would do the job successfully by loading the page then "Ctrl + S" (Save as ..) to save the xml file without any problems.

What the differences between browser and WebClient API ? Is there additional action which the browser implements ?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: this is probably because the link you provided is not to the resource directly, but the xml is fetched through some javascript I don't feel like trying to understand at the moment

Comment: @slawekwin If it is fetched through javascript can I get the root link to the resource ? Or the resource itself is inaccessible ?

Comment: I wouldn't know that, where did you get the link in the first place? simple F12 investigation of the page did not produce any immediate solutions for me

Comment: I initially found that link from an online quiz game. It load questions by passing that URL to its engine